# Question Regarding a Second Order Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I was wondering if the solution to the following differential equation belongs to a class of special functions. If not, is it exactly solvable?

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+(\beta+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\alpha}{x(x-1)})\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{\kappa^{2}}{x(x-1)}y=0
\end{equation}

where $\beta$, $\alpha$ and $\kappa$ are real numbers.

With a change of variable I was trying to fit it in the Hypergeometric or Heun class of differential equations, but no success yet!

Comment: How come? if you check the requrality of this D.E. we will find that it is irreqular. so cannot use series solution near 0 nor 1. This means the discontinuity points are non-removable so cannot have analytic solution.

Comment: Nope! $x=0$ and $x=1$ are both regular singular points.

Comment: Yes you are right... sorry

Comment: This is the [confluent Heun equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E1).

Comment: @Startwearingpurple: What form of CHE are you referring to?

Comment: Notice the coefficient of $\alpha$ in my equation above. It's $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$. If it was only $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{x-1}$ then you were right.

Comment: @Ben $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac1x$.

Comment: Oops! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to have an answer, I slightly expand my comment:

This ODE is a particular case of the [confluent Heun equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E1)
$$\frac{{d}^{2}w}{{dz}^{2}}+\left(\frac{\gamma}{z}+\frac{\delta}{z-1}+\epsilon%
\right)\frac{dw}{dz}+\frac{\alpha z-q}{z(z-1)}w=0,$$
with $\left(\alpha,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon,q\right)_{\text{Heun}}=\left(0,1-\alpha,\alpha,\beta,\kappa^2\right)_{\text{OP}}$.